# To what extent is the quality of a sperm sample affected during transit via mail from the donor's home to a cryobank?

Tags: sperm, sperm-count

To what extent is the quality of a sperm sample affected during transit from the donor's home to a cryobank?

I found https://intercom.help/legacyfertility/en/articles/4307725-is-my-sample-affected-during-transit

> Your volume, count, concentration and morphology are not affected by
> the transit. This is simply a reflection of how much sperm you are
> producing and their shape.
>
> You can expect a small decline in the motility of the sperm, dependent
> on the number of hours in transit. The decline ranges from 5-20%, with
> an average of about 10%.

https://www.dadikit.com/faq/:

> Is there a loss in sperm motility due to transport of sperm? The kit's preservative is used to protect the sperm on its journey back to the lab. Loss in sperm motility is generally between 10–15%.

However, the websites don't give any source for their statements, and since they are a cryobank that only accept customers' sample by mail, they have a conflict of interest.

Comment: I'm really surprised one can send such thing in mail, was sure it's possible to give a sample only in their labs so it's placed in storage right away. Anyway what I wanted to say is that I doubt you will get official answer, as it's not something that is being officially researched, and  the cyrobanks themselves won't perform such a research "for real" as the likely results (actual decline in quality of the sperm) will harm their profits.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou "the cryobanks themselves won't perform such a research "for real" as the likely results (actual decline in quality of the sperm) will harm their profits." -> unless the cryobank didn't provide the mail  option :-) Also there are plenty of researchers outside cryobanks with no conflict of interest. So hopefully someone have done / will do such a study!

Comment: I could find the relevant citations when I have some time, but I seem to remember some research findings that show that sperm quality is better when ejaculated outside a lab building which is curious. This could account for wishing sperm samples to be brought in from home, but mailing the sample would in my mind affect quality more. Interesting question.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Interesting, if you recall these studies I'm interested:  [Is the sperm quality is better when ejaculated outside a lab building better than if in a lab building?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/24552/20241)

Comment: I am sorry to say that looking for reputable sources it sounds like I was reading a report which gave false information at the time. See [Licht et al. (2008)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.fertnstert.2007.02.033) and [Song et al. (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.fertnstert.2007.01.051)